# How to find any methods ancestor chain?

Tags: ruby

```
class Taco
  # . . .
end
```

Get ancestor chain:

```
Taco.ancestors
 #=> [Taco, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Say I want to find the "parent" class and it's ancestor chain for a ruby defined method. How would I go about doing that?

E.g. `method_missing.parent.ancestors`

And if *everything* is supposed to inherit from `BasicObject` why doesn't `Kernel`?

```
Object.ancestors
 #=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Kernel.ancestors
 #=> [Kernel]

BasicObject.ancestors
 #=> [BasicObject]
```

Also `Class` inherits from `Class` and `Module` but why does my `Taco` class ancestor's chain not inherit from them and instead inherits directly from `Object` forward?

```
Class.ancestors
#=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically regarding your question: "Also `Class` inherits from `Class` and `Module` but why does my `Taco` class ancestor's chain not inherit from them and instead inherits directly from `Object` forward?"

`Taco` is an *instance* of `Class`, but its *superclass* is `Object`. An instance relationship and a superclass relationship are 2 completely different things.

For example: imagine you create a class `Animal` with a subclass `Dog`. `Animal.new` will give you an object which is an *instance* of `Animal`. The `Dog` class is *not* an instance of `Animal` (it is not itself an animal -- rather, it defines a type of animal). Its *superclass* is `Animal`.

Every object is an instance of some class -- call `class` to find out which one. But not all objects have a superclass -- only instances of `Class` do.

Additionally, `Class` does not inherit from `Class`. That is impossible. *All* classes appear at the beginning of their own `ancestors`, but that doesn't mean they inherit from themselves. That is just how the `ancestors` method works.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for [owner](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-owner).

```
method(:puts).owner 
  #=> Kernel
method(:puts).owner.ancestors
  #=> [Kernel]
```

Back to your taco example:

```
class Taco
  def self.eat
    "YUM"
  end
end

Taco.method(:eat).owner
  #=> #<Class:Taco>
Taco.method(:eat).owner.ancestors
  #=> [Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Kernel is an instance of `module`.  Check this out:

```
Kernel.class.ancestors
  #=> [Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Here is some [further reading](http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model) on the ruby object model if you're interested. Also, here's an image stolen from google images that may help solidify those concepts.

[image: ruby object model]

Comment: Hey that's cool. Can you shed some knowledge on the other parts of the question too? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I do `Taco.method(:eat).owner.ancestors` I get back `[Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: Nevermind I get same as you when I `def` as `self` I had `def eat "yum" end`

Comment: What's your take on this: **And if everything is supposed to inherit from BasicObject why doesn't Kernel?**

Comment: I see you're using pry. *Now I'm even more confused.* How is `Kernel` an instance of `Module` and `BasicObject`?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. `Kernel.class.ancestors` I think this just means the *ancestors* of the `class` of `Kernel` Thanks for the link.

Comment: @feed_me_code bribery for rep is absolutely not acceptable on SO and destroys the organic content validation mechanism.  If I am wrong, someone will tell me or down vote.  If I am right and help someone else, they will up vote.  Violating that and voting incorrectly only hurts the site and its usefulness.